# Javascript grab div and place it in between different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

```
<div id='layer1'></div>
<div id='layer2'></div>
<div id='layer3'></div>
```

I have 3 divs, I want those div can be draggable and adjust the layer like photoshop changing layers.

ex. When user grab layer1 and place between layer3 & layer2 (mouse up).

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure some people here know how to do that, but they would be expecting you to show some effort first.

Comment: Are you trying to implement http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **Sortable** from [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/).

Basically you need to have a structure like this:

```
<ul class="sortable-list">
  ...
  <li>...</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

And then in your jQuery code, just call:

```
$('.sortable-list').sortable();
```